# Não trazer duplicadas com uma determinada condição em um SELECT

Tags: sql

Preciso construir uma consulta que remove duplicidades de uma coluna personalizada (concatenada) se determinada coluna for X valor.
Por exemplo:

```
SELECT emp, cod, vev, gru, concat(cast(emp as char(20)), cast(cod as char(20))) as RES
from hcov 
  CASE 
    WHEN GRU = 212 THEN GROUP BY RES END
```

Tentei montar esta consulta mas da erro:

```
SQL Error [700]: [Elevate Software][ElevateDB] ElevateDB Error #700 An error was found in the statement at line 4 and column 4 (Expected end of expression but instead found WHEN)
```

Basicamente, o que eu preciso é remover duplicadas da coluna concatenada somente se a coluna GRU for 212.

Answer (score 0):

Fernando, acho que você pode deixar o Group By com a coluna *res* e utilizar o Case para acrescentar outra coluna que não duplica caso a coluna GRU seja diferente de 212.
Exemplo consideando que a coluna *emp* não duplica:

```
from hcov 
GROUP BY RES, CASE WHEN GRU <> 212 THEN emp END
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: desculpe sou um pouco leigo neste assunto, não sei se desta forma vai me ajudar pois eu postei aqui um exemplo da consulta, na verdade o que entrará em produção a coluna concatenada teria 6 campos e não apenas 2 como eu fiz no resumo aqui.. teria alguma outra lógica para este caso?

Comment: acredito que a quantidade de colunas concatenadas não vai afetar o resultado, o importante é você colocar uma coluna que não duplica onde no exemplo está a coluna emp. tente fazer uns testes para ver o que acontece

Comment: qualquer coluna pode duplicar...  o que eu preciso é que a consulta use a coluna concatenada para verificar se possui duplicidade quando o GRU for 212.. e caso exista traga somente uma.. para os demais GRU deverá trazer mesmo duplicadas.. entendeu?

Comment: Existe alguma coluna ou conjunto de colunas na tabela que não duplica? Qual banco de dados e versão você está utilizando?